Can Section 4 of the SOA 2003 ever be applied to online catfishing?
Section 4 of the SOA 2003 deals with non consensual sexual activity.
Sections 74-76 deal with the definition of consent and conditions whereby consent would be vitiated.
I have seen it argued by some that someone sending nude images to a catfish online could be considered under section 4 by virtue of the fact that sending nudes could be considered a sexual activity and that section 74 could be used to suggest that they did not have the freedom to choose to consent as they were being deceived by the gender/ identity of the other party.
Case law states that section 76 doesn't apply, especially in Bingham 2013, as the deception to identity was peripheral to the nature and purpose of the act. 74 would have only applied if coercion was used.
additionally in that case the sexual activity took place via webcam and did not involve the sending of images.
74 has been used in cases of digital penetration and gender deception with McNully but only as far as it removed the complainants freedom to choose which gender the activity occurred with and by virtue of the fact that under 76 it changed the nature of the sexual activity.
So ultimately are we left with clarification that sections 4 74 and 76 cannot be used in this way mostly due to the decision in Bingham (2013)?
Certainly there has never been a charge made against anyone regarding catfishing situations that did not involve a blackmail element and catfishing has only ever been considered in criminal law if it led to fraud.

Re. "took place via webcam and did not involve the sending of images"... how does "via webcam" not involve sending images?

Video, by definition, is always images.

@TripeHound a webcam stream is not a pre recorded image, it's a live stream. Sending someone an image or a video is not the same as going on webcam for someone to view. But that wasn't the essential point I was making.

@Cardgame482, we understand that, but the distinction between the images is one of past tense vs present tense WRT time they are created.  If you think that distinction is important to your question then please explain why.

@MichaelHall I think the distinction is that the only case law involving online sexual activity and deception involve performing sexual acts on live on webcam. There is no case law that attempts to extend sexual activity to include the exchanging of sexual images or even sexual messages.
